# pass family= to step() via glm() programmatically

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to demonstrate via simulation the performance of different models and feature selection techniques, so I wish to pass various arguments to `glm()` programmatically.

Under `?glm` we read (italics mine):

> **family**:  a description of the error distribution and link function to be used in the model. For glm this can be a *character string naming a
>   family function*, a family function or the result of a call to a family function. For glm.fit only the third option is supported. (See family for details of family functions.)

The problem is that when I then call `step()` on the resulting model, there seems to be a scoping problem and the `family=` parameter is no longer recognized.

Here is a minimal example:

```
getCoef <- function(formula, 
                family = c("gaussian", "binomial"),
                data){

  model_fam <- match.arg(family, c("gaussian", "binomial"))

  fit_null <- glm(update(formula,".~1"), 
                   family = model_fam, 
                   data = data)

  message("So far so good")

  fit_stepBIC <- step(fit_null, 
                      formula, 
                      direction="forward",
                      k = log(nrow(data)),
                      trace=0)

  message("Doesn't make it this far")

  fit_stepBIC$coefficients
}

# returns error 'model_fam' not found 
getCoef(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, family = "gaussian", data = iris)
```

Error message with traceback:

```
> getCoef(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, family = "gaussian", data = iris)
So far so good

 Error in stats::glm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, family = model_fam,  : 
  object 'model_fam' not found 
9 stats::glm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, family = model_fam, 
    data = data, method = "model.frame") 
8 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
7 eval(fcall, env) 
6 model.frame.glm(fob, xlev = object$xlevels) 
5 model.frame(fob, xlev = object$xlevels) 
4 add1.glm(fit, scope$add, scale = scale, trace = trace, k = k, 
    ...) 
3 add1(fit, scope$add, scale = scale, trace = trace, k = k, ...) 
2 step(fit_null, formula, direction = "forward", k = log(nrow(data)), 
    trace = 0) 
1 getCoef(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species, family = "gaussian", 
    data = iris) 

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.1.11 tools_3.2.4
```

What is the most natural way to pass this parameter so that is recognized by step?  One possible workaround I'm aware of would be to call `glm()` with the explicit family name via if-then-else conditioned on `model_fam`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I get `object fit_stepAIC not found` but if I change it to `fit_stepBIC` works fine.

Comment: @ErnestA whoops that's a typo in copying it over, hang on

Comment: @ErnestA - so you don't get the above error when you run the above script?

Comment: @C8H10N402 no error, I get the coefficient values. Maybe try running it in a clean R session and see if the error disappears.

Comment: @ErnestA thanks for your time -- I still get the error in a clean session (updated with info).  Are you on R 3.2.4?  I wouldn't think that OS would have anything to do with this...

Comment: @C8H10N402 OK, I'm getting the error now. I was running it step by step with no error, but if I run it as a script I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following solution, based on `eval`, `bquote` and `.()` might solve your problem.

I also have R-version 3.2.4 installed, and I got the exact same error you got from your code. The solution below made it work at my computer.

```
getCoef <- function(formula, 
                family = c("gaussian", "binomial"),
                data){

    model_fam <- match.arg(family, c("gaussian", "binomial"))

    fit_null <- eval(bquote(
        glm(update(.(formula),".~1"), 
            family = .(model_fam), 
            data = .(data))))

    message("So far so good")

    fit_stepBIC <- step(fit_null, 
                        formula, 
                        direction="forward",
                        k = log(nrow(data)),
                        trace=0)

    message("Doesn't make it this far")

    fit_stepBIC$coefficients
}

# returns error 'model_fam' not found 
 getCoef(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Species,
        family = "gaussian",
        data = iris)

So far so good
Doesn't make it this far
      (Intercept) Speciesversicolor  Speciesvirginica       Petal.Width 
         1.211397          1.697791          2.276693          1.018712
```

Comment: So basically, `eval` is forcing evaluation in the `getCoef` environment?  As opposed to lazy evaluation that would occur inside the `step`?  Is that what my problem was?

Comment: I think the problem with the first approach was that the component `fit_null$call` gave this `glm(formula = update(formula, ".~1"), family = model_fam, data = data)`.  The `bquote` and `.()` inserts the argument value we need, and the `eval` is needed since `step` doesn't automatically evaluate the quoted expression.  I'm not quite certain about all the technical details, but I have figured out that quotes often solves such problems you encountered in your case.

Comment: I thought ErnestA's answer nailed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `step` eventually calls `model.frame` and `model.frame` evaluates the terms object in a special environment, namely the environment in which the formula was defined. That will normally be the environment from which `getCoef` is called. But in this environment `model_fam` doesn't exist because it is defined inside `getCoef`. One way to fix it is adding

```
environment(formula) <- environment()
```

after

```
model_fam <- match.arg(family, c("gaussian", "binomial"))
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: Nice analysis. If you step into the evaluation frames after running with `options(error = recover)` and look at the value of `envir` at level 7 you get: <environment: R_GlobalEnv>. I was running with version 3.3.0 but R version shouldn't matter since this is an expected result.