# Passing glm family into function and compare two fitted models using a likelihood-ratio test

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a function that imputes data, fits models, and compares models. I would like to be able to pass the glm family into the function. However, that does not work.

```
library(mice)

fun_1 <- function(my_data, my_family) {

  imp <- mice(my_data, seed = 51009, print = FALSE)

  mi1 <- with(data = imp, expr = glm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, family = my_family))
  mi0_1 <- with(data = imp, expr = glm(bmi ~ age + hyp, family = my_family))
  mi0_2 <- with(data = imp, expr = glm(bmi ~ age + chl, family = my_family))

  lapply(list(mi0_1, mi0_2), function(x) mice::D3(fit1 = mi1, fit0 = x))

}

fun_1(my_data = nhanes2, my_family = "gaussian")
```

When I run that function I get an error:

```
 Error in glm(formula = bmi ~ 1, family = my_family, data = cbind(data,  : 
  object 'my_family' not found
```

I was surprised since passing the family into that function here works well:

```
fun_2 <- function(my_data, my_family) {

  glm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, family = my_family, data = my_data)

}

fun_2(my_data = nhanes2, my_family = "gaussian")
```

And if I only pass the data into fun_1 then everything runs well

```
fun_3 <- function(my_data) {

  imp <- mice(my_data, seed = 51009, print = FALSE)

  mi1 <- with(data = imp, expr = glm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, family = "gaussian"))
  mi0_1 <- with(data = imp, expr = glm(bmi ~ age + hyp, family = "gaussian"))
  mi0_2 <- with(data = imp, expr = glm(bmi ~ age + chl, family = "gaussian"))

  lapply(list(mi0_1, mi0_2), function(x) mice::D3(fit1 = mi1, fit0 = x))    

}

fun_3(my_data = nhanes2)
```

Strangely enough it is not the regressions that fail in fun_1 but it is the likelihood ratio test (D3) later on.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750217/pass-family-to-step-via-glm-programatically

Comment: The eval, bquote and .() approach worked. Thanks!

Comment: Like: mi1 <- with(data = imp, expr =  eval(bquote(glm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, family = .(my_family)))))